# Is it known if in Overlord the action is set in a "real world" or in a "game world"?

Tags: overlord

I think this is still unknown. But I don't know all the content of Overlord in detail.

References have been made that, for example, Ains, and the rest of either NPCs, or potentially other players, where transported to a "new world".

But, as far as I know, it's unknown if he has been transported to a "real world" where he and all characters have now a physical body that matches the one they had in the game, or if what Ains, and any other possible player that was trapped in the world, perceive is just a extremely accurate virtual simulation.

I know that, at this point of the story, his real physical body would be long dead under normal circumstances, but I think things like that all his mind was copied while he was sleeping when the game server closed, and then transferred to some computer, or that he was kidnapped and now his body is in a Matrix-like state somewhere don't contradict anything that is on the story.

Is there any hint or evidence on which type of world the story is really happening?

Comment: Kind of related? [To what extent is Momonga living in the current world in which this anime is set?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24161)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is mentioned in the light novels.

**Spoiler alert for those who only read the Manga and/or watch the Anime:**

> It's strongly indicated that it is indeed a real world and that this isn't the first time. There are characters who know of these Players and know how mighty they can be. One example is Evileye from the all-female adamantium group Blue Rose. She is actually Landfall from the Thirteen Heroes who defeated the demon gods, who are indicated to have been players like Ainz.

Comment: can you provide source where it mentioned?